Numba and Numpy Generator Methods & Thread Safety Documentation Clarification
The Numba documention for the Numpy Random module states:

The current Numba support for Generator is not thread-safe, hence we do not recommend using Generator methods in methods with parallel execution logic.

I am interpreting this as...
rng = np.random.default_rng()

@njit
def this_is_ok(rng):
    # Sequential execution code...

@njit
def this_is_not_ok(rng):
    # Parallel execution code...

And that parallel calls to this_is_ok(rng) are OK, using multiprocressing or Dask for example? Or, do I have to pass a separate generator instances?

Using Numba generators with multiprocessing is fine but you need the seed to be setup correctly per process so to avoid  them being equal and generate the same values. In Numba, a code is not parallel if you do not specify the flag parallel=True, assuming you do not call the Numba function in parallel yourself.

In general, in parallel codes, you need 1 RNG per thread. If you do not, then the RNG generally needs to be protected. Fast shared thread-safe RNG are not possible because the communication between cores is what make things slow (or unsafe if not synchronized properly).

Thank you for your comments. So if I do something like this it should be OK...this_is_ok(rng=np.random.default_rng(seed), which can then be run in parallel with Dask, say... [dask.delayed(this_is_ok)(rng=np.random.default_rng(seed) for seed in range(10)] whiere each thread is given a different instance of a rng with a differing seed.

This seems fine to me (though details often matters). Note that Numba can spawn threads too and it is often more efficient than running Numba functions with another parallel systems (CPython's multithreading is limited by the GIL and multiprocessing by data transfer not to mention Numba does not mix up well with multiprocessing due to replicated JIT overheads)
